# Why I can surf to my site through my custom nameservers ns1.mydomain.ltd? (Webmin)

Tags: webmin

I using Webmin for my VPS.
In Webmin > BIND DNS Server I configured a new master zone with custom nameservers ns1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD and ns2.MY_DOMAIN.TLD and glued them to my domain.
This is my master zone recorded file:

```
$ttl 38400
MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  SOA ns1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD. MY_EMAIL. (
            1588938949
            60
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  NS  ns1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD.
MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  NS  ns2.MY_DOMAIN.TLD.
MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  A   MY_SERVER_IP
ns1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  A   MY_SERVER_IP
ns2.MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  A   MY_SERVER_IP
MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  MX  10 mail.MY_DOMAIN.TLD.
www.MY_DOMAIN.TLD.  IN  CNAME   MY_DOMAIN.TLD.
```

Why when I go to ns1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD or ns2.MY_DOMAIN.TLD in browser it's show my site MY_DOMAIN.TLD?